# GNUPG - issue with spaces in folder name

Tags: python, gnupg

The .py file and the file to decrypt are in the same folder.
If the folder name has spaces, the function returns False, otherwise it returns True and it correctly decrypts the file.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG()

# monkey patch....
if os.name != 'nt':
    import gnupg._parsers
    gnupg._parsers.Verify.TRUST_LEVELS["DECRYPTION_COMPLIANCE_MODE"] = 23


SelectedFile = os.getcwd() + '/myfile.cx'
outputfile = SelectedFile.split('.cx')[0] + '.dx'

path = os.path.dirname(SelectedFile)

with open(os.path.abspath(SelectedFile), 'rb') as f:
    status = gpg.decrypt_file(
        f,
        passphrase='mypassword',
        output=outputfile,
    )
    print (status.ok)
```

Note that I tried to separate the 2 files and I realized that the issue is related with the folder containing the .py file.

Comment: Can you create an example reproducer that doesn't require tkinter? Can you confirm that this happens across platforms (or, alternately, that it's a Windows-only bug)? Also, which gnupg module for Python are you running? (Is it the branch maintained by Isis Lovecruft, or a different one?)

Comment: (BTW, just to be clear -- despite having my name as one of the folks who's had patches accepted into the tree, python-gnupg is awful, and I don't recommend anyone use it; personally, I stopped using Python for any OpenPGP-related code entirely, and cut over to Go's [`x/crypto/openpgp`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp), which -- while disowned by its authors -- is a far higher-quality implementation).

Comment: (...whereas if I were building a new design that required comparable functionality, I'd probably go with [`saltpack`](https://saltpack.org/), as a protocol designed with explicit intent to avoid OpenPGP's flaws).

Comment: The tkinter package is not required, was a mistake from my side to insert it. See the updated code. I am compiling on mac, but the issue occurs also on windows.

About openpgp I am totally agree with you, unfortunately I am working on a multi-component project where the decision to use openpgp was already established.